# Explicit formula for a multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

Do you know any explicit formula for the multiplication:
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2) ...(x-x_n)$$

It should be an explicit easy formula, but I cannot find it ...

Comment: Personally I think it is easy enough. Probably you would want to expand it but it is even complicated with no conditions imposed on  $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.

Comment: I need the coefficient of $x^k$ when $k=0,...,n$

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking up the elementary symmetric polynomials. For example, if $n = 3$, then you find that the expression is equal to
$$
x^3 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)x^2 + (x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3)x - x_1x_2x_3
$$
where the coefficients are elementary symmetric polynomials in three variables.

Comment: I should remark, to be clear: Each of the coefficients is symmetric under any permutation of the variables $x_i$, which is why symmetric polynomials arise.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** try multiplying the formula for $n=2$, $n=3$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use induction on $n$. Here is a way: For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $s_1(n) := \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i, s_2(n) := \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}x_ix_j, s_3(n) := \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n}x_ix_jx_k,\cdots$ and $s_k(n) = 0$ for $k \geq n+1$. 
Also define $\Delta_n := (x - x_1)(x - x_2) \cdots (x - x_n).$ Assume $\Delta_{n-1} = x^{n-1} - s_1(n-1)x^{n-2}+ \cdots +(-1)^{n-1}s_{n-1}(n-1).$ Then $\Delta_n = \Delta_{n-1}(x-x_n).$ 
The co-efficient of $x^{n-i}$ in the expression for $\Delta_n$ is $(-1)^{i}(s_{i}(n-1) + s_{i-1}(n-1)x_n).$ Now use the expressions for $s_i(n)$ to show that $s_i(n) = s_{i}(n-1) + s_{i-1}(n-1)x_n.$